# UAC - embedding manifest for .net

Tags: .net, uac

C++ projects have a linker option to embed manifest to require UAC elevation (/MANIFESTUAC:level) .

Is there any such option for .net projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008: add an item of type "Manifest file" to your project, then select in on the Project Properties - Application page.

If not, you need to use `mt.exe`, the Microsoft Manifest Tool. See [this article on certifying an application for Windows Vista](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/certificationbyexample.aspx) (written by me, by the way): one of the things it explains is how to embed a manifest file on a Visual Studio 2005 solution, you could use the same approach for other environments as well.